# webpack/metro mainFiles module resolution with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, webpack

**Setup**

Webpack has a [mainFiles](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemainfiles) module resolution which allows you to resolve some files depending on environment, like:

```
| Button
|   | - index.ts
|   | - index.performer.ts
|   | - index.customer.ts

// Page.ts
import Button from './Button';
```

Similar works in react-native's [platform-specific module resolution](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#native-specific-extensions-ie-sharing-code-with-nodejs-and-web).

You can import button depending on a platform (environment, in other words)

```
| Button
|   | - index.ts
|   | - index.android.ts
|   | - index.ios.ts

// App.ts
import Button from './Button';
```

**Question:**

How to tell typescript to resolve those import, 
and select correct file depending on environment?

The behavior is that webpack/metro will selects index.android.ts, but typescript think that we imported index.ts.

Thats the problem.

Comment: Similar issue, I just dropped this idea. I currently don't know any framework having this to work. A palliative is to reexport the environment you consider to be the default in `index.ts`, so this file always exist.

Answer (score 0):

2 years later... Check typescript moduleSuffixes